# HTML <base> TAG and local folder path with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am trying to use **< base>** TAG to indicate the source folder containing the media files for my html pages located in separate folder.

I have the following folder structure:

```
A
|- HTML_PAGES        (contains html files)
|- MEDIA_FOLDER      (contains the media used by this html pages)
```

I try to indicate the html files with the media used by html pages - so, in each html file i have something like this:

```
<base href="../MEDIA_FOLDER"/>
```

And the problem is: it works for some browsers (Opera, Chrome) but it doesn't work for Internet Explorer and Firefox. How to make it work with IE and Firefox?

Comment: Which version of IE? IE8 has a bug where BASE tags are not properly respected for pages/resources using the FILE URI Scheme. Firefox has a security restriction that grants a local HTML page access only to subpaths of the main page.

Comment: And that is again problem of the crappy Internet Explorer that one runs into …

Answer (score 33):

This is definitely a very annoying bug in IE, but I just found a workaround.

The thing to realize is that IE does resolve the relative path, and then promptly ignores it. You can even see the fully resolved URL by checking the value of the base tag's 'href' property later on using JavaScript. So this (rather silly) piece of code resets the `<base>` tag's 'href' attribute to the very full URL that IE had already resolved, thereby causing it to no longer be ignored.

Add the following HTML to the top of your page, right after the  tag and before you actually use any URLs:

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">
    // Fix for IE ignoring relative base tags.
    (function() {
        var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
        baseTag.href = baseTag.href;
    })();
</script><![endif]-->
```

*(conditional comments necessary since this code can break the `<base>` tag in Safari/Chrome, and other browsers clearly don't need it.)*

Such a silly bug.

Comment: This saved me big time. I have some test html files deep in the hierarchy of my project (which could be hosted from different paths, so the URLs need to be relative) and setting the base href definitely helps. `<base href="../../../..">` I just need to figure out the dots once! Great work!

Comment: It was in test case html files that I hit this bug as well. Common use for `<base>` tags. Glad to help! :)

Comment: Tried this, but I'm getting the exact same behavior as previously: works in Firefox (with or without the script), but in IE 8 the URLs are the same as if base href was not set (ie, my base href="../..", the calculated URLs are 2 directory levels too deep).

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 9):

It looks like there are two separate issues with IE8 and IE9.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/c51bb8b9-40ab-437b-a125-88b660f3e1ca/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/e5cfdf07-494c-4703-aa4a-34a1a548de05/

A workaround that seems to be working in IE8 and IE9 is including http:// in the base href. I am not experiencing any issues in Firefox (v9)

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute URL:

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/MEDIA_FOLDER"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the pages are single html files that refer to the media locally, without web server. Anyway - it might work?

Comment: Using absolute URLs is not an acceptable solution when pages usually travel through multiple environments these days before they end up in production.

Answer (score 2):

```
<base href="../MEDIA_FOLDER"/>
```

Doesn't have a trailing slash, so it refers to a *file* called `MEDIA_FOLDER` and not a folder. Often you don't notice the difference because web servers will redirect an attempt to fetch `folder` to the proper address `folder/`, which will then typically return a default document (eg. `folder/index.html`). But for relative URL resolution it does make a difference.

`target` relative to `/folder` is not `/folder/target`, it's just `/target`. To make it `/folder/target` you must let the browser know that the base URL is a folder, by adding a trailing slash:

```
<base href="../MEDIA_FOLDER/"/>
```

There is no reason for different browser behaviour here. A place you may find different browser behaviour, though, is if you've accidentally used a Windows-filesystem-style backslash `\` instead of `/`, so do check for that.

Comment: You're right about the trailing slash, but:
<base href="../MEDIA_FOLDER/"/> works fine for Opera and Chrome, but not for IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer got me close to the working solution, here is what I ended up adapting it to.

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">
    // Fix for IE ignoring relative base tags.
    (function() {
        var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
        baseTag.href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + baseTag.href;
    })();
</script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how BASE works with directory relative urls, try giving it a root relative url like

```
<base href="/MEDIA_FOLDER"/>
```

Comment: Actually you are talking about using of site rooted paths which must start with `/`. It could be a good idea to end them with `/` too.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `base` element inside the `body` element? That could cause the problem. (Check in Firebug, it might end up in the `body` even if your code looks okay on first sight.)

Comment: my html code:
<html>
<head>
<base href="../media_folder/"/>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and it's that IE requires closing the tag but not Firefox, the other browsers simply don't care. Here is what works for me:

```
<base href="{BASE_PATH}"><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
```

Feel free to tweak at your will, and of course replace {BASE_PATH} with your actual path, i normally use an absolute path, but i've seen this work for relative too

**EDIT:** And please note that your path should end with a trailing slash

Comment: That made no difference for me testing in IE 9. Only using an absolute URL fixed it.

Comment: i am sorry it hasn't made any difference to you but this IS a known bug. See http://ruthsarian.wordpress.com/2006/01/31/ie-base-tag-bug/
Now please remove your downvotes

Answer (score 0):

I consider that people reading this are dealing with enterprise or legacy web applications.

We can't rely on the **IE Conditional Comments** as it just might be ignored by IE, believe it or not. At least, it is my persisting case.

I added below my script which is browser features' agnostic.

It was tested in IE11 under IE-5-7-8-9-10-11 render modes with HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
With the **IE Enterprise mode** and without.

It works for relative paths like `../MEDIA_FOLDER/`.

It works for `my_child_folder/MEDIA_FOLDER/` with the exception of IE7-5.
I'm a little lazy to fix it and encourage you to use rooted paths.
I.e. simply use `/some_root_folder/my_child_folder/MEDIA_FOLDER/` instead of `my_child_folder/MEDIA_FOLDER/`. *(Or improve my script, or do not use IE7-5.)*

We have two main bugs here and a bunch of cases.

First, IE9 and IE8 auto-convert a path value in the href attribute to an URL. They do this, just like all modern browsers.
But IE page doesn't see this auto-change. We just fix this by re-assining of the href `baseTag.href = baseTag.href`.

Second, IE7-5 do not produce auto-conversion of a path value to an URL value. We should do it manually.

There are other situations which slightly change IE behavior. This depends on

- What DOCTYPE do you use.
- How do you render you base tag - `<base/>`, `<base></base>` or `<base>`.
- How your **IE Enterprise Mode** deals with **IE Compatibility View** setting.

For example if you have the **IE Enterprise Mode** set to IE8 with the **Compatibility View** set on then IE will set IE7 User-Agent HTTP header and ASP.NET Forms will be rendering for IE7.
Or the **IE Conditional Comments** will be ignored in case of pop-ups, frames, iframes or on common pages. These are all my real cases.

```
(function () {
    // Fixes old IE wrong behaiors of the href attribute of the base tag.

    var preventIeHrefIgnoring = function (baseTag) {
        var docMode = document.documentMode;
        var isIe = docMode;
        if (!isIe)
            return;
        if (docMode != 8 && docMode != 9)
            return;

        // IE8 and IE9 auto-convert path-like values of the href attribute, but do not apply it on the page.
        // It is fixed by re-assining.
        baseTag.href = baseTag.href;
    }

    var baseColl = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
    if (!baseColl.length)
        return;
    var baseTag = baseColl[0];

    var initialHref = baseTag.href;
    if (!initialHref)
        return;

    var hrefIsUrl = initialHref.indexOf("https://") == 0 || initialHref.indexOf("http://") == 0;
    if (hrefIsUrl) {
        preventIeHrefIgnoring(baseTag);

        return;
    }

    // Below we are dealing with IE7-5 only.

    var targetHref = initialHref.indexOf('/') == 0 ? initialHref : "/" + initialHref;

    var resultHref = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + targetHref;
    baseTag.href = resultHref;
})();
```