# Resource mapping Spring framework 3

Tags: java, spring

I'm facing following problem actually:

I'm using Spring with jQuery. I have Controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/A")
public class AController {
    // not important
}
```

That is handling all `host/A/...` URLs fine. But jQuery CSS styles are using `url(images/...)`, so there are references from `host/A/index.jsp` to `host/A/images/...`. But I have no such folder since /A/ is just "logical" URL.

I tried to add

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/A/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

to my web.xml, but it seems it is not working (first one is working fine). For example when I try to test this, `host/A/test.png` is not working.

Of course I can modify jQuery sources, but I do not preffer this way.

Maybe I can use [UrlRewriteFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something#1483362) if there is not simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [BASE](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag in your resulting HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <base href="http://localhost:8080/myApp/" />
       ....
```

Then, all your image request will be done to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/images/...` whether if you are located in `http://localhost:8080/myApp/` or in `http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/`

Comment: Just note for others, there is [problem with base tag in IE8 and IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer).

Comment: @Betlista: It's not a bug. As the W3Schools link says: `The base URL must be an absolute URL!`.

Comment: But IMHO `<base href="/myApp/" />` is not relative URL (it starts with '/' so it's absolute), but it is not working in IE8 and IE9...

My opinion is that it is not good practice to have host name in page - in development-testing-production cycle there are different host names. In my JSP I used `<%= %>` to generate this, in pure HTML that is a problem I think.

Comment: @Betlista: No, it's an absolute URL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and). I must agree with you about not hardcoding your hostname. So, another reason why never use pure HTML. I  use a custom taglib or velocity macro which gets the correct value from a properties file. Sometimes more sofisticated logic is required if you are behind a proxy, for example.

Comment: base tag is causing [form submitting with opening new window problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825612/why-form-submit-opens-new-window-tab), just letting others know...

Comment: @Betlista: I was following that interesting question too. Very strange behaviour. Thanks to advice us!

Comment: base tag is ok, I had `target="_blank` in it (copied from w3schools) :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a app server like tomcat, you can do this in your web.xml file:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

In my projects, normally I put something like this ;)

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.PNG</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.swf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.avi</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this, you need to create a 'physical' "./A/images/" folder.

In another application server, the  value can change.

Comment: Hm, but in this way I have to copy images multiple times for all logical URLs `/A/...`, `/B/...`, I do not like the idea. If I'd like to do that, then simple `<mvc:resources mapping="/A/images/**" location="/A/images/" />` will work exactly the same way.

Comment: Oh, okok.... then, I don't know an answer without using UrlRewriteFilter.... sorry :(