# Why form submit opens new window/tab?

Tags: java, html, forms, spring, spring-mvc

I found a lot of questions ["How to open form result in new window"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring%20form%20new%20window), but I'm facing opposite problem.

I have form:

```xml
<form:form method="post" commandName="search">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Then I have controller with handling method

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/search.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit( @Valid final SearchObject searchObject, final BindingResult bindingResult ) {
    if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) return "forms/search";
    return "redirect:/A/result.form";
}
```

Everything works fine, except the fact that result is opened in new window/tab.

Solution that I found and is working is to add target attribute:

```xml
<form:form method="post" commandName="search" target="_self">
```

But `_self` is default AFAIK.

I'm wondering why is that happening.

I checked generated HTML and it seems to me ok:

```xml
<form id="search" action="/myApp/A/search.form" method="post">
```

**edit** added headers

```
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 22 Mar 2012 16:29:13 GMT
Location    http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/result.form
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=E9ACB44C4ED3814814ABE7D96C90135C; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=cs_CZ; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/search.form
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Response Headers From Cache
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  0
Date    Thu, 22 Mar 2012 16:29:13 GMT
Location    http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/result.form
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length  64
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded


GET sessions.form

200 OK

localhost:8080

309 B

::1:8080


6ms
HeadersResponseCacheHTML
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  309
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 22 Mar 2012 16:29:13 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=E9ACB44C4ED3814814ABE7D96C90135C; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=cs_CZ; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/myApp/A/search.form
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
```

**edit 2** added method for result.form

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/result.form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String result() {
    return "forms/result";
}
```

My controller class starts with:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/A")
public class AController {
```

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour when you siable Javascript?

Comment: Behaviour is the same with disabled JS.

Comment: What about on different browsers? Do other websites and links work ok?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I've had a bug where my browser did this on all forms. Restarting resolved it.

Comment: It's doing in all my browsers (IE9, FF11, Chrome17).

Comment: Interesting. Do you see any suspicious response headers?

Comment: I do not know what to look for, but I edited the question and added what I found in Firebug, maybe there is something incorrect, but I cannot see it...

Comment: Try to isolate completely the form in a JSP with no other code that the form and see if the behaviour is still the same. Also, print with an alert what is the target value when submit is clicked.

Comment: What does the controller method for /result.form (GET) look like?

Comment: @GriffeyDog: method added to question

Comment: Form target has value undefined. I checked this when form is submitted by JavaScript and also in footer of the page (also by JavaScript).

Comment: I probably found the reason - I have [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) in HTML head, but still do not understand such behaviour. (When base is commented, it's submitted in same window in FF). I added base tag because of [problem with resources handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805282/resource-mapping-spring-framework-3).

Comment: @Betlista: I've used BASE tag in several applications and I have never seen this behaviour. I must take a look on it! You should answer your own question and accept it. You won't get any point, but people viewing this question will see easily the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was in [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). I had intentionally `target="_blank"` in tag, probably because I copied the example from w3schools :-/

Comment: For those of you who don't have `target="_blank"` in `<form>` tag, this is most certainly the solution.