# Mod_rewrite overwrites all link in the page

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I am using following mod_rewrite rule:

```
  **RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]**
```

to get clean url such as

```
  www.myweb.com/login
```

from

```
 www.myweb.com/login.php
```

I am using another rewrite rule

```
**RewriteRule ^itemdetail/([0-9]+)/?$ itemdetail.php?itemid=$1 [NC,L]**
```

to get

```
 www.myweb.com/itemdetail/100008
```

from

```
 www.myweb.com/itemdetail?itemid=100008.
```

This works fine but there is one problem. This rewrite rule add a subdomain on every link. for example. if the link to css file is text.css now the link to this css file is itemdetail/text.css. The link to home page is now www.myweb.com/itemdetail/home instead of www.myweb.com/home. What am I doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This rewrite rule add a subdomain on every link. for example. if the link to css file is text.css now the link to this css file is itemdetail/text.css. The link to home page is now www.myweb.com/itemdetail/home instead of www.myweb.com/home. What am I doing wrong here.

You can do one of two things to deal with this, either add this to the header of your `itemdetail.php` pages (inside the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Or you can change your css links from relative to absolute URLs by adding a leading `/`, example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/text.css" type="text/css">
```

Otherwise, you could try adding rewrite rules to un-write the css links, but that's usually a really bad idea, as it'll break css in subdirectories when you are intentionally using them:

```
RewriteRule ^itemdetail/(.*?)\.css$ /$1.css [L]
```

Comment: does IE support <base href="/"> ?

Comment: @Hari there are peculiar bugs involving the `<base>` tag and different versions of IE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973975/851273 Also I think older versions of IE (6 maybe?) may not support it at all.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently IE requires whole href than just "/".