# Base URL in Internet Explorer and JSP

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, jsp, servlets

Internet Explorer doesn't support HTML `<base> tag and even other browsers do, there are some problems when redirect takes place in`servlets`to some`.jsp`pages for example`request dispatching.`

It's feasible to add `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` with each URL
nor `request.getServletPath()`

JSP relative links for CSS and images with servlets forwarding may change things a lot. This link : [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

**Is there a better approach with JSP / servlets or it's just an IE issue?

Link : [HTML <base> TAG and local folder path with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer)**

**And if it is an IE issue:

1. how to fix the IE issue as the above post is unable to give a valid answer?

2. how to solve it with JSP / servlets?**

My website is now showing CSS and images.
E.g. HTML output is:

```
<base href="http://localhost:8080/Alpinema/" /> is not working for 
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
```

It works in other browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

My JSP code portion:

```
<head>
    <base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(uri))}${req.contextPath}/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alpinema.com</title>
    <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
   /css?family=Merriweather|PT+Sans:700|Nobile:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Uggggh `<base>` is terrible. Surely JSP has a proper way to handle project-relative URLS?

Comment: @Pekka are you asking in the comment of a question?

Comment: Not really, I'm saying you should go look for a better solution to your problem :) (the downvote is not mine, though.)

Comment: @Pekka thats why iam here. to look for a better solution. see the bold lines in the question

Answer (score 4):

Use `<c:url>` tag from JSTL to reference CSS/JavaScript resources inside my JSP files. By doing so you can be sure that the CSS/JavaScript resources are referenced **always relative to the application context** (context path).

---

### Example

*index.jsp:*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Some Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/main.css" />" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/utils.js" />"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

---

For even more solutions see my answer here:
[Adding external resources (CSS/JavaScript/images etc) in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571407/814702).

Comment: nice! its off now. give me some time to test it.  and   when using web templates or some site made by some other developer. its hard to change all links to c:url

Comment: @Masood I use JSTL tags, as I code all JSP files myself. No problems so far. For instance, in the example above, the "css" and "js" folder are both located in the root folder. And the path in the value attribute MUST start with forward slash ("/some_path") in order to be relative to the context path. Sorry if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: @Masood And of course the right JAR libraries also must be present in your WEB-INF/lib folder. See here for the details:http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: it works great! Thanks but for template sites (thats my work) , I am looking for a proper solution. I want to rate this answer but my reputaion is < 15

Comment: @Masood It's OK, no problem )) I upvoted your question to get rid of -1. Hope someone will help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help (from the Microsoft MSDN page related to Internet Explorer): "When used, the **base element must appear within the head of the document, before any elements that refer to an external source**." See "Remarks" and "Example" here (scroll down): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: added 3 ignore some urls in html output are /Alpinema/path/file and some are path/file . I added ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ to each, so not consistent. and thats the only way I found as solution (not preferred nor for template sites( thats what I do))