# spring static resources issue

Tags: spring, jsp, resources

I'm missing all the static resources in my JSP file view. I have been using below controller and dispatcher servlet configuration.

dispatcher-servlet file in a spring 3.0.1 application

```
context:component-scan base-package="com.iop.outreach"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/><mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Sample JSP file

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css" />
```

Requests hit the below controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/superadmin")
public Street Controller {


}
```

it looking for resources in `<applicaton_rootname>/superadmin/resources` instead of `<application_root>/resources/`

I'm not sure where this is happening ?

Comment: put a slash in front the path, e.g. *location="/resources/css/style.css"*

Comment: As a variant you can use JSTL `<c:url>` tag. Seee the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063039/814702

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />
```