# Adding external resources (CSS/JavaScript/images etc) in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, assets, el

I added an external CSS stylesheet to my project and placed in the WEB-CONTENTS folder of my project in Eclipse. When I deployed it on the Tomcat, the stylesheet was not applied. When I debugged it in Chrome and opened it, it gave me `404 file not found` error. Why is that and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>joined now </title>

<link href="globalCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div>this is at the top</div>
<c:import url="header.jsp" />
<c:import url="navigationBar.jsp" />  
<c:import url="leftpane.jsp" /> 
<c:import url="mainContent.jsp" /> 
<c:import url="rightpane.jsp" />
<c:import url="footer.jsp" />  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The URL you used to load the CSS file is obviously incorrect. Post your HTML code and tell us the URL used to display the HTML page.

Comment: And what are the paths to all of these in the workspace project?

Comment: the css is in same folder as the jsp page accessing it,i.e WEB-CONTENTS. So I don't think that path is the problem here.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3655316

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The reason that you get the `404 File Not Found` error, is that your path to CSS given as a value to the `href` attribute is missing **context path**.

An HTTP request URL contains the following parts:

```
http://[host]:[port][request-path]?[query-string]
```

The *request path* is further composed of the following elements:

- *Context path*: A concatenation of a forward slash (/) with the [**context
  root**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/webapp004.htm#BNAEP) of the servlet's web application. Example: `http://host[:port]/context-root[/url-pattern]`
- *Servlet path*: The path section that corresponds to the component
  alias that activated this request. This path starts with a forward
  slash (/).
- *Path info*: The part of the request path that is not part of the
  context path or the servlet path.

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets005.htm#BNAFW).

---

## Solutions

There are several solutions to your problem, here are some of them:

### 1) Using `<c:url>` tag from JSTL

In my Java web applications I usually used [`<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tag from [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) when defining the path to CSS/JavaScript/image and other static resources. By doing so you can be sure that those resources are referenced **always relative to the application context** (context path).

If you say, that your CSS is located inside *WebContent* folder, then this should work:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/globalCSS.css" />" />
```

The reason why it works is explained in the "*JavaServer Pages™ Standard Tag Library*" version 1.2 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.2-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/) chapter 7.5 (emphasis mine):

> **7.5    <c:url>**
>   Builds a URL with the proper rewriting rules applied.
>   ...
>   The URL must be either an absolute URL
>   starting with a scheme (e.g. "http:// server/context/page.jsp") or a
>   relative URL as defined by JSP 1.2 in JSP.2.2.1 "Relative URL
>   Specification". As a consequence, an implementation must **prepend the
>   context path to a URL that starts with a slash** (e.g. "/page2.jsp") so
>   that such URLs can be properly interpreted by a client browser.

*NOTE*
Don't forget to use *Taglib directive* in your JSP to be able to reference [JSTL tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html). Also see an example JSP page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063039/814702).

### 2) Using JSP Expression Language and implicit objects

An **alternative** solution is using [Expression Language (EL)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to add application context:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/globalCSS.css" />
```

Here we have retrieved the context path from the *request* object. And to access the request object we have used the *pageContext* [**implicit object**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij).

### 3) Using `<c:set>` tag from JSTL

*DISCLAIMER*
The idea of this solution was taken from [here](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/07/09/looking-up-context-path-on-a-jsp-page/).

To make accessing the context path more compact than in the solution №2, you can first use the JSTL [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) tag, that [sets the value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakj) of an EL variable or the property of an EL variable in any of the JSP scopes (page, request, session, or application) for later access.

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${root}/globalCSS.css" />
```

*IMPORTANT NOTE*
By default, in order to set the variable in such manner, the JSP that contains this *set* tag must be accessed **at least once** (including in case of setting the value in the *application* scope using *scope* attribute, like `<c:set var="foo" value="bar" scope="application" />`), **before** using this new variable. For instance, you can have **several** JSP files where you need this variable. So you must ether a) **both** set the new variable holding context path in the *application* scope AND access this JSP first, before using this variable in other JSP files, or b) set this context path holding variable in EVERY JSP file, where you need to access to it.

### 4) Using ServletContextListener

The more effective way to make accessing the context path more compact is to set a variable that will hold the context path and store it in the *application [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718683/814702)* using a [*Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets002.htm#BNAFK). This solution is similar to solution №3, but the benefit is that now the variable holding context path is set **right at the start** of the web application and is available application wide, no need for additional steps.

We need a class that implements [*ServletContextListener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface. Here is an example of such class:

```java
package com.example.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
        sc.setAttribute("ctx", sc.getContextPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {}

}
```

Now in a JSP we can access this global variable using EL:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${ctx}/globalCSS.css" />
```

*NOTE*
[@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation is available since Servlet version 3.0. If you use a servlet container or application server that supports older Servlet specifications, remove the *@WebServlet* annotation and instead configure the listener in the *deployment descriptor* (web.xml). Here is an example of *web.xml* file for the container that supports maximum Servlet version 2.5 (other configurations are omitted for the sake of brevity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    ...  
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.listener.AppContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
</webapp>
```

### 5) Using scriptlets

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548998/adding-external-resources-css-javascript-images-etc-in-jsp/14571407?noredirect=1#comment54508429_14571407) by user [*@gavenkoa*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173149/gavenkoa) you can also use [scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scriptlet/info) like this:

```
<%= request.getContextPath() %>
```

For such a small thing it is probably OK, just note that [generally the use of scriptlets in JSP is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702).

## Conclusion

I personally prefer either the first solution (used it in my previous projects most of the time) or the second, as they are most clear, intuitive and unambiguous (IMHO). But you choose whatever suits you most.

---

### Other thoughts

You can deploy your web app as the *default application* (i.e. in the **default root context**), so it can be accessed **without specifying context path**. For more info read the "Update" section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225540/814702).

Answer (score 2):

**Using Following Code You Solve thisQuestion.... If you run a file using localhost server than this problem solve by following Jsp Page Code.This Code put Between Head Tag in jsp file**

```
<style type="text/css">
    <%@include file="css/style.css" %>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@include file="js/script.js" %>
</script>
```