# How to import a CSS file in JSP?

Tags: jsp, include, include-path

```
<%String path = application.getRealPath("/");%>
<%@page import="index.css" %>
```

I am using String path as above to get the real path of my directory. I want to import index.css from the css folder.

Is it possible in JSP to do something like `<%@page import = path+"css/index.css"%>` or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to import a css file on the server-side?

Comment: I am coming from a php background so I am used to using include_once and being done with it. Is there nothing similar in JSP? @MattHouser

Comment: @Aaron: That's not how CSS works.  CSS runs on the **client**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding external resources (CSS/JavaScript/images etc) in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548998/adding-external-resources-css-javascript-images-etc-in-jsp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to include index.css file to jsp.
try this

```
<jsp:include page="index.css"/>
```

or

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/include/header.jsp"%>
```

but i recommend to use  tag in html

Comment: This is what I wanted. Just wanted to know how to include the CSS file in jsp using a jsp include. Thanks!

Comment: Youtube link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Neither PHP nor JSP have anything to do with CSS.

You can link the **resulting HTML** to a stylesheet the same way you would in any other HTML, using the `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

execute css codes from within the jsp page using the it works for me

```html
<style>
        .container {
          alignment-adjust: central; 
        }
</style>
```