# Java web app error_404 on css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, java, css, web, servlets

this is my very first Java webapp and I'm trying to integrate a template bootstrap(https://github.com/colorlibhq/AdminLTE) as my front end.

I'm getting the 404 error, GET http://localhost:8080/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 and i cant seem load all the files needed for my index.jsp file

This is my project structure: [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE1Oz.png)

I cannot seem to find the right URL to access the files.They plugins for example are located inside **Webcontent > assets > admin > plugins**

I tried using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` but it hasn't worked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/WebContent/assets/admin/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
```

I honestly dk what is going on and can i also ask the difference between Java resources and Web Content?
I would really appreciate it if you were to share resources with me on developing web applications using java, so far.

Comment: Hi everyone, i see similar issues but they are abit dated, if my explanation sucked, perhaps these might help. please help! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129121/cant-access-css-and-javascript-files-in-jsp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal

Answer (score -1):

YOu have to give relative path of your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./WebContent/assets/admin/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
```

Comment: it didn't work too :( it gave me the same result as when i used " ${pageContext.request.contextPath}  "

Comment: you should inspect you browser and check what file path you getting in network tab

Comment: basically all my js and css files are unable to be found :/ must be smth to do with the path but i cant figure it out