# How to apply external HTML or CSS templating to jsp pages (NetBeans)

Tags: java, html, css, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm new to Java environment and I want to know:

1) **How to apply external HTML or CSS files to jsp pages**(Web Application using NetBeans)

2) Is there **any 'MasterPage' alternative feature in Java?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can either put CSS code directly in your JSP, or link to it, as usual, the real difference is where to put resources, and how to link to theme, I refer you to this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571407/1951298
for external HTML file, you can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) :  `<c:import url="http://website.com/some/portion.html" />`