# Java - CSS file not loading

Tags: java, html, css

I have a `.jsp` file

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Calendar</title>
<h1><div align="center">My Sunlife App</div></h1>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css" media="screen"> 

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <script  type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">


   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();


  });
  </script>


</head>
```

It is using a css file (`BackgroundIMGE.css`) which sets the background image. I have placed this css file in my `Workspace\MySunlifeApp\cssFiles\BackgroundIMGE.css`.
Name of application using this is `MySunlifeApp`.

The css file is:

```
body {
background-image: url(/asd.jpg); /*You will specify your image path here.*/

-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here `asd.jpg` is also in the same folder as the CSS file.
When I am running the application, it is not loading the CSS file.

```
http://localhost:8090/MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/BackgroundIMGE.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Where is the css file ? In which folder ?

Comment: try to remove the slash `background-image: url(asd.jpg);`

Comment: try adding / to the css url

Comment: @Blobonat, He is using a jsp ;) and a 8090 port

Comment: what about the asd.jpg? is it loading from http://localhost:8090/MySunlifeApp/cssFiles/asd.jpg

Comment: @AxelH css file is in folder(named cssFiles) which is in my workspace under MySunlifeApp (name of the application)

Comment: @mic4ael i had done that. No impact!!

Comment: Yeah!! Though i have a doubt. The location of  localhost:8090/MySunlifeApp is  Workspace/MySunlifeApp??? @DanielMiron

Comment: Does your HTML page correctly load `BackgroundIMGE.css`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding external resources (CSS/JavaScript/images etc) in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548998/adding-external-resources-css-javascript-images-etc-in-jsp)