# How to redirect in web.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a GAE/J app and I have the following structure:

```
- war
    |
    - mobile
    |      |
    |      - assets
    |      |      |
    |      |      + a.jpg
    |      |      + b.gif
    |      |      + c.js
    |      + a.jsp
    |      + b.jsp
    |      + index.jsp
    |      + d.css
    |      + e.css
    |
    + landing.jsp
```

Now in web.xml, I have a URL mapping of `/mobile`  pointing to `<jsp-file>/mobile/index.jsp<jsp-file>`. In my `index.jsp`, I used relative addressing to reference all the required resources like JS files, CSS files and images; and this works well if I type `our_domain/mobile/index.jsp` in the browser. But when I type `our_domain/mobile`, it serves the correct file (index.jsp) but every relative address breaks which means no CSS, no JS, no image.
From my investigation, it seems that `web.xml` doesn't actually redirect but rather calls a specified JSP/Servlet to answer to a specific URL pattern. This does not work well with relative addressing as path information that would be correct with a real redirect is left at the root. How do I ensure that relative addresses work as expected in this kind of scenario?

[edit]
I've tried sevral configurations. Now `/mobile` URL works properly and all my CSS gets loaded but `/mobile/` doesn't load my CSS. Here's my mapping:

```
<servlet> <description>Landing page on mobile site</description> 
 <display-name>MobileIndex</display-name>
 <servlet-name>MobileIndex</servlet-name>
 <jsp-file>/mobile/index.jsp</jsp-file> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MobileIndex</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/mobile/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MobileIndex</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/mobile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is your mapping look like?

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MobileIndex</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/mobile</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>`

Where `MobileIndex` is also declared in `web.xml` as the servlet name pointed at the `/mobile/index.jsp` file.
When dis didnt work, I even pointed `MobileIndex` at another JSP whose only purpose was to do a `response.sendRedirect("/mobile/index.jsp");` but dat didnt work either. I then changed d redirecting JSP 2 a standard servlet s accomplish d same purpose but it also didnt work as expected. They all redirected but my CSS & JS files stil couldnt b located.

Comment: Why do you use the web.xml to map a jsp to a path where it is? Do you really need a servlet? Any way this is just a misconception not your problem. How do you reference your resource files (eg. CSS/JS/IMGs)?

Comment: relative addressing, e.g `<link href="d.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
The reason why I mapped it that way is that I want my users to be able to just type `my_domain/mobile` in their browser instead of `my_domain/mobile/index.jsp`

Comment: What if you use this href="./d.css"?

Comment: Same result. Question updated.

Comment: @SayoOladeji Check out my answer that shows how to solve the problem of referencing CSS/JavaScripts etc in JSP files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063039/814702

Comment: @SayoOladeji, was the solution proposed by effective for you. If so, what specific changes had you made to your mappings shown above?

Comment: Is this issue still occurring?

Comment: @Nick I just checked and the issue is no longer present. I can't remember what I did to get it to work as I've not been maintaining the project for a long time. If this is an issue that you are experiencing I can investigate.

Comment: No worries, I was just wondering if you still needed assistance! Glad to hear. I guess this question will go without an answer. I'm not really sure what the Stack Overflow guidelines are for a situation like this...

Comment: @Nick thanks a lot. I did see anything interesting in the repo. I noticed I later took down `/mobile` entirely. I'm incredibly grateful for all the assistance I received on this thread. Kindly pardon me, it's been over 3 years. I was juggling balls in that period and so wasn't very organized; then we discontinued the project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure redirect is what you actually want.  A good organization for your app is:

`myapp/
  pom.xml
  src/
    main/
      java/
         ... Your Source Code ...
      webapp
        landing.jsp
        assets/
          a.jpg
          b.gif
          c.js
        mobile/
          index.jsp
          a.jsp
          b.jsp`

You can, of course, change the location of your assets using the `<public-root>` and `<static-files>` elements of [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref).