# <base> does not work on IE7

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am using `<base href="/">` it seemed to work like magic! but when I test the website on IE7 on windows XP the website got messed up! nothing works at all[image].

Is there anything I need to add to the .htaccess to fix the problem? I have also found this fix:
[HTML <base> TAG and local folder path with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer) but the guy who asked did not really pick it a good answer...

What do you guys suggest? `<base href="/">` is placed on the head and all the links on the website looks like "`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">`" or "`<a class="button" href="page.php">I am a Button</a>`"

Comment: Are you putting the `<base>` tag in the `<head>`? Can you show a little bit of relevant code?

Comment: How you refer to your images/files in code?

Comment: I placed "<base href="/">" in the head and all my links are like "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">"

Comment: why you need to put that at all in there?? It's not needed..

Comment: Because I have many links and pages in sub directories ect, and the base link will take them all to the root first

Comment: That can be done in .htaccess..

Comment: @Hardy please can you show me how? please!

Comment: Do you have apache ? or iis?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48064/discussion-between-loai-and-hardy)

Comment: `<base>` is very laborious, you may prefer to use absolute path (a good practice is CDN - "subdomain").

Comment: Can I then use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in <base href="">?

Answer (score 0):

I have used "`<base href="<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) {echo 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; }else{echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];}?>/" />`" and it worked perfectly.