# IE or EDGE ignores the base tag no matter what I do. How to bypass this?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

This is my situation:

I'm trying to create multilingual site and for that I have the select input:

```
<select id="select-lang" onchange="location = this.value">
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>   
<span id="demo"><?php echo $_["TEXT"] ?></span>
```

In my htaccess I have this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteRule ^(fr|de)$  $1/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|de)/$  index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

to work properly I needed to add the base tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://myIPaddress:8080/demo/">
</head>
```

If I wouldn't add the base tag I would get this when switching languages (two langs at the end):

```
http://myIPaddress:8080/demo/fr/de
```

and the base tag works fine on all browsers except IE and EDGE. They behave like it wasn't there. I've read about this on the internet and I tried all deferent things like use full path (not only `<base href=/demo/>`), use close tag `</base>` or even JS for reassigning the href ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer)), but nothing has worked for me. Please help how to bypass this situation, how to fix the base tag, or how to change htaccess or even how to rewrite this demo code, so I wouldn't need to use the base tag?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem (maybe someone who will be struggling with similar problem will benefit from this). As I said in my post, for all browsers it was enough to switch languages correctly just by adding `<base>` tag like this:

`<base href="/demo/">`

but for IE and EDGE I also needed to add the relative path (like for base tag) in each SELECT's option:

```
<select id="select-lang" onchange="location = this.value">
    <option value="/demo/de">German</option>
    <option value="/demo/fr">French</option>
</select>
```

even this the base tag still needs to be present for CSS and JS files to load properly. I can't explain this technically but for me it means that IE and EDGE they see the base tag but only for proper loading css or js files, but not for when changing location in onchange function.