# internet explorer is removing context root of my angular app? any way to avoid?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

let's say i have deployed my angular 5 app in http://www.example.com
and my app context root is sampleapp.
in chrome & firefox i can access by visiting http://www.example.com/sampleapp
but if i use internet explorer when i visit http://www.example.com/sampleapp
it is removing /sampleapp from url address bar and serving the app, but i want my context root for some reason,
how to prevent removing of context root in internet explorer?

Comment: i too face the same

Answer (score 0):

I guess you set the base href to a relative path. IE can not handle relative paths.

Here is a workaround:

[HTML <base> TAG and local folder path with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer)

Answer (score -1):

I solved it setting tag *base* in index.html in a proper way, it was set to "." and it was wrong.
Specifically, you must set it to your application context root. In your case, sampleapp.
So, in your index.html will be

```
base href="/sampleapp/"
```

If you don't use IE11, you'll never need this silly trick

Hope it helps someone